# iOS 8 Cannot connect to BLE. Can connect to in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Made an app on iOS 9 that find and connects to BLE. But when I run it on iOS 8 nothing happens. It does not find anything. I guess it should run on `func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)` in `if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)` case. But when I run it that function in not called. On iOS 9 it works fine and and calls that func.

```
import CoreBluetooth
import Foundation

class BeaconConnection: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

private static var connectedBeacon: BeaconConnection?

static func sharedInstance() -> BeaconConnection {
    if connectedBeacon == nil {
        connectedBeacon = BeaconConnection()
    }
    return connectedBeacon!
}

let centralManager = CBCentralManager()
var connectedPeripheral:CBPeripheral?
var peripherals: Array<CBPeripheral> = Array<CBPeripheral>()

func initializer() {
    centralManager.delegate = self
}

func connectToPeripheral(index: Int) {
    print(peripherals[index])
    connectedPeripheral = peripherals[index]
    centralManager.stopScan()
    connectedPeripheral!.delegate = self
    centralManager.connectPeripheral(connectedPeripheral!, options: nil)
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral)
    if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
    }
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("centralManagerDidUpdateState")
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff) {
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn) {
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized) {
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unknown) {
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown")
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported) {
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform")
    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("didConnectPeripheral")
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
    print("failed to connect")
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
    print("didDisconnectPeripheral")
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print("willRestoreState")
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service)
    }
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

}
}
```

Comment: Make sure the target you compile it for matches the platform your trying to run it on. I had a few issues with code like this. So if its an iPad running 8.x make sure you compile it for 8.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was here

```
centralManager.delegate = self
```

In iOS 9 it works, but in iOS 8 should be like this

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```

And even can delete this func

```
func initializer() {
centralManager.delegate = self
}
```

and write like this

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}
```